# remy inliner command line tool returns path.existsSync is now called `fs.existsSync`

Tags: node.js, command-line

I'm trying to use [inliner command line tool](https://github.com/remy/inliner) locally to combine some files. But I get the following error message in the console.

```
path.existsSync is now called `fs.existsSync`
```

So i went into /usr/local/lib/node_modules/inliner/bin/inliner and changed line 65 from:

```
if (path.existsSync(url))
```

to

```
if (fs.existsSync(url))
```

but I get still the same error message. Can anybody give me a hint what is wrong and how I can fix this?
There is already a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327740/anyone-have-idea-how-to-use-inliner-remy-inliner) but that didn't fix my problem. Or am I editing the wrong file?
Cheers
:fab

Comment: There is probably other instance where path.existsSync is being called .

Comment: I looked thru the files and found another `path.existsSync(url)` in [inliner.js](https://github.com/remy/inliner/blob/master/inliner.js) I also changed that but still no result. Now the error message is gone but inliner does not create any file.

Comment: Got it working. It seems like the the image to binary compression is making problems. With: `inliner -vi http://fabiantheblind.github.com/timeremap-source/ > test.html` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got inliner working by using the `-i` command

```
#-i, --images    don't encode images - keeps files size small, but more requests  
inliner -i http://fabiantheblind.info/coding.html > test2.html
```